# i need some help creating Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i need to hide the extensions of my webpage and also want to let the user put the links in both (lower and upper) case:

Example:

the file name is demo.php

www.example.com/demo
www.example.com/DEMO
www.example.com/Demo

Running PHP in a LAMP server, no access to php.ini, just .htaccess

Actualy im using a file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(OUTSOURCING|outsourcing|Outsourcing)$ outsourcing.php [NC,L]
```

And i m reciving this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /outsourcing was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: as you would need 2go to http://example.com/outsourcing// for that to work use the second example i gave in my answer

Comment: it seems htaccess is not working :S, know how to activate or something like that? im using your 2nd example

Comment: ask your host as you do need access to the httpd.conf file

Comment: they told me that the htaccess is running okay, my script is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
```

www.example.com/DEMO www.example.com/Demo or doing www.example.com/DEMO/page2

```
RewriteRule ^/(DEMO|demo|Demo)/(.*)$ demo.php?=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/(DEMO|demo|Demo)$ demo.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/(D|d)emo$ demo.php [NC,L]
```

or pass anything www.example.com/DeMo www.example.com/bob to demo.php

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ demo.php [NC,L]
```

you may want to test if your allowed .htaccess `RewriteRule /*$ http://google.com [R][L]`

Comment: not working, it shows me: Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: now it shows a 500 internal server error, changed the error but still nothing, doesnt redirect

Comment: can you edit your question with what code your using... i cant see your screen

Comment: htaccess is running but bad they told me that there is a mistake in the script

Answer (score 1):

here is a good way to do it with case insensitive method

EDIT:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${lc:$1}.php [NC]
```

this way anything entered will be redirected to a php file.

edit : this way your js and css file can still run

Comment: but thats not what the OP asked for

Comment: Also, add rules to prevent matching files that actually do exist, otherwise you're going to mess up all the CSS, images and javascript being served up as well.

Comment: From what i understand he/she wants to remove the extension so this will do the trick, `index.php` can be entered `index`

Comment: @Lawrence - it depends, the user says that demo is an *example*, not the only page they want to rewrite; this is a more general solution than just rewriting demo.

Comment: the OP asked how do i hide extension and specified a file "demo"... who designs scripts with multiple files for each page, if that the case may as well just hard code it...

Comment: Yes, having to write rules for each page would be stupid; which is why this general solution is better than the page specific solution that you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/[Dd][Ee][Mm][Oo]/?(.*)$ demo.php [NC,L]
```

will redirect any capitalization of "Demo" to demo.php

Answer (score 0):

First add this line in the `<VirtualHost>` section OR at the end of your httpd.conf file (**to enable lc function in .htaccess for later use**):

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then have these rules in .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond ${lc:%{REQUEST_FILENAME}}.php -f
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}}.php [L]
```

- First rule in .htaccess is doing **external redirect** by making a URI of `/index.php` to `/index`
- Second rule in .htaccess is doing **internal redirect** by makign a URI of `/INDEX` to `/index.php` by lowercasing the URI. Assuming you have filename index.php physically present.

That way you can always write URLs without `.php` extension.